# iOS/How to change JTCalender's firstDay at weekMode

Tags: ios, calendar, jtcalendar

I use `JTCalender` in my project.
I change the mode to week mode and set the `maxDate` as today with `[NSDate date]`, and set the `minDate` as the day one week before, but the first day is still Sunday not the `minDate`'s weekday, and the `maxday` still is the Saturday, not the current day.

Comment: can you post a link the the calendar you are using?

Comment: @swiftnub sorry, here is the link   https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar

Comment: oh, ok then sorry, i thought you were using another calendar library JTAppleCaneldar. Nvm.

Comment: @swiftnub.  Well, I even can't find the JTAppleCaneldar you mentioned in Google.....

Comment: you can [find it here on cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/JTAppleCalendar) or [here on github](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar)
I think you couldn't find it because i spelled it wrong for you haha.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jonathantribouharet/JTCalendar/issues/277

> You misunderstand the minDate and the firstWeekDay property of NSCalendar which can be set directly or you can set a locale (which is better for internationalization).

```
_calendarManager.dateHelper.calendar.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fr_FR"];
```